# How to specify the arguments to a function passed to a Scala map (Higher Order) Function?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I have a function f that takes two arguments - a:Int and b:Int

`f (a:Int, b:Int): Int`

I wish to call map on a List of 2-tuples - such that for each tuple (a,b) in the list, I wish to map it to f(a,b).
How will I do it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do this.

First, and perhaps most clearly for readers, you can destructure the tuple in the `map`:

```
val tuples: List[(Int, Int)] = ???  // code to generate the list
tuples.map {
  case (a, b) => f(a, b)
}
```

Second, you can convert a function into one which takes a tuple as an input with `.tupled`.  Methods defined with `def` have to be turned into a function first:

```
val tupledF = (f _).tupled
val tuples: List[(Int, Int)] = ??? // code to generate the list
tuples.map(tupledF)
```

Comment: Thanks, I am getting the below error -> ``` scala> val seq_xs =  (Seq.fill(degree)(x)).zipWithIndex.map((exp _).tupled)
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.reduceLeft
  at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.reduceLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:139)
  at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.reduceLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:138)
  at scala.collection ```

Comment: @BhawandeepSingh this error has nothing to do with your question. You are just calling `reduceLeft` on an empty sequence somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, it was failing for the case when degree is 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do `l.map { case (a,b) => f(a,b) }`. Or a clever way: `l.map((f _).tupled)`

Comment: Thanks, I am getting error with both. First one -> ```scala> val seq_xs =  (Seq.fill(degree)(x)).zipWithIndex.map { (a,b) => exp(a,b) }
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, Int) => Int
 required: ((Int, Int)) => ?
       val seq_xs =  (Seq.fill(degree)(x)).zipWithIndex.map { (a,b) => exp(a,b) }
```.

Comment: 2nd one -> ```  scala> val seq_xs =  (Seq.fill(degree)(x)).zipWithIndex.map(exp.tupled)
<console>:14: error: missing argument list for method exp
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `exp _` or `exp(_,_)` instead of `exp`.
       val seq_xs =  (Seq.fill(degree)(x)).zipWithIndex.map(exp.tupled)
  ```

Comment: @BhawandeepSingh oops. Fixed it. [Try now](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/xmDZRHzuTxqmr2vENYuWxw).

Comment: @BhawandeepSingh yeah, that error has nothing to do with this, it's just a bug in your code somewhere.